# How to split a FULLTEXT index between multiple match against

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have the following full text index:

```
FULLTEXT INDEX `title_short_description_description` (`title`, `short_description`, `description`)
```

When I run the below query I get this error:

> Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

```
select (
    (match (title) against ('abc' in boolean mode) * 100) +
    (match (short_description, description) against ('abc' in boolean mode))
) as score

from game_cache

where

    match (title) against ('abc' in boolean mode) or 
    match (short_description, description) against ('abc' in boolean mode)

order by score desc
```

I assume that this is because I am not using all three columns in the same match, but instead separating them between 2 matches. I have tried separating the indexes, but MySQL doesn't allow for that.

Is there any way I can make this query work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a separate index for each distinct set of columns you want to query using `MATCH`.

In order to run your example query, you need to add two more `FULLTEXT` indexes (one at a time):

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
  ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `index_on_title` (`title`);

ALTER TABLE your_table
  ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `index_on_short_description_and_description` 
    (`short_description`, `description`);
```

If you never run any queries that checks for matches on all 3 columns, then you should consider dropping your existing `FULLTEXT` index:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
  DROP INDEX `title_short_description_description`;
```

Comment: That is strange, last time I tried to add 2 fulltext indexes it gave me an error saying that their can only be one on the table... But now it works...

Comment: You probably tried to add them both in a single `ALTER TABLE` statement, which is not supported (for `FULLTEXT` index specifically).

Comment: Yeah, that is what I did.